# Filling a queue from another queue in reverse order

Tags: scala, queue

It is also too easy maybe. How can I fill the B queue by A queue? but B queue must be reverse.

Comment: Have added "queue" and "homework" tags (this looks so much like homework that I assume that this is what it is).

Answer (score 1):

What about just

```
val b = a.reverse
```

Comment: Returns a MutableList, not a Queue.

Comment: Are you sure? The Scala docs says it returns, "A new immutable queue with all elements of this immutable queue in reversed order."

Comment: Yes, I'm sure :) The scaladoc seems to be wrong or this is a bug `scala> var q = scala.collection.mutable.Queue(1,2,3)
q: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3)

scala> q.reverse
res15: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int] = MutableList(3, 2, 1)`

Comment: Ah, you're using mutable Queue. I was looking at scala.collection.immutable.Queue `scala> var q = scala.collection.immutable.Queue(1,2,3)
q: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3)

scala> q.reverse
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(3, 2, 1)
`

Comment: That's very odd. Sounds like the Mutable behaviour is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Queue is a FIFO, if you can take from the end of the queue, just take from the end of A and put them into B.

If you can't, take A from the front, insert them on a Stack, then when A is empty, put them off the stack into B.

Comment: But A will be empty after I fill the B. How can I save both A and B with its qeueu?

Comment: make a third queue and insert into it when you insert it into the stack. this queue will be identical to A. if you need them back in A take out of the third one and reinsert into A